# Pandas group bp, filter and extract row depending on the condition

Tags: python, pandas

```
d = {'ID': ['H1', 'H1', 'H2', 'H2', 'H3', 'H3'], 'Month': ['01/06/2020', '01/06/2020', '01/08/2020', '01/08/2020', '01/07/2020', '01/07/2020'], 'Check': ['H', 'S', 'H', 'S', 'H', 'S'], 'Unit': [10, 0, 10, 0, 10, 5]}
df_input = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I `groupby` the input dataframe (`df_input`) by `ID` and `Month`, and extract rows which are equal to the `groupby` sum of `Unit`. For example, I expected the output to look like:

```
d = {'ID': ['H1', 'H2'], 'Month': ['01/06/2020', '01/08/2020'], 'Check': ['H', 'H'], 'Unit': [10, 10]}
df_output = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I have tried with this:

```
df_input.groupby(['ID', 'Month']).filter(lambda x: (x['Unit'] == sum(x['Unit'])).any())
```

But it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DataFrame.transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) to create a series of sum by ID and Month and filter your df by that series

```
filter_cond = df_input.groupby(['ID','Month'])['Unit'].transform('sum')
df_output = df_input[df_input['Unit'] == filter_cond].reset_index(drop = True)


    ID  Month   Check   Unit
0   H1  01/06/2020  H   10
1   H2  01/08/2020  H   10
```

Here is another option (just to explain how to make your solution work) but it won't be optimum,

```
df_input[df_input.groupby(['ID', 'Month']).apply(lambda x: (x['Unit'] == x['Unit'].sum())).reset_index(drop = True)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
#I used df instead of df_input
df[df.set_index(['ID', 'Month']).eq(df.groupby(['ID', 'Month']).sum()).values]\
  .reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
    ID  Month   Check   Unit
0   H1  01/06/2020  H   10
1   H2  01/08/2020  H   10
```